# Why does sbt report UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES for Spark 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT jars?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

My sbt file contains following content

```
name := "Simple Project" 
version := "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT" 
scalaVersion := "2.10.4" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

On running the project by `sbt package` I get the following error:

```
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/roott/SparkProjects/checkProject/) 
[info] Updating {file:/home/roott/SparkProjects/checkProject/}default-9d4332... 
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ... 
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core;1.3.0-SNAPSHOT ... 
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core;1.3.0-SNAPSHOT 
[warn] ==== local: tried 
[warn]   /home/roott/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml 
[warn] ==== public: tried 
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spark-core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: 
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core;1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: not found 
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
[error] {file:/home/roott/SparkProjects/checkProject/}default-9d4332/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core;1.3.0-SNAPSHOT: not found 
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 28-Dec-2014 16:49:50
```

What does the error mean and how to fix it?

Comment: There isn't anything on search.maven.org

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Spark project publishes `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` binaries anywhere so you're supposed to build Spark locally and reference it in your project.

When you build Spark following [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) using Apache Maven as the build tool you will need to add the local Maven repository to your sbt build using `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`. Read [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Resolvers) in the official documentation of sbt.